# Getting image data from canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have two functions to display image data from a canvas, which contains some image .

This works

```
var canvasElement = document.getElementById("Canvas"),
canvas = canvasElement.getContext("2d");

canvas.fillStyle = "#ff6633"
canvas.fillRect(0,0,200,200);

for(x=0;x<200;x=x+10){
   for(y=0;y<200;y=y+10){
   p = canvas.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
   console.log(p[0] + " " + p[1] + ' '+p[2]+' ' +p[3]);
  }
}
```

but this doesn't

```
var canvasElement2 = document.getElementById("Canvas2"),
canvas2 = canvasElement.getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();  
image.src = "b.png";  

$(image).load(function() {  
       canvas2.drawImage(image, 0, 0,200,200);  
});

canvas2.drawImage(image, 0, 0,200,200); 

for(x=0;x<200;x=x+10){
          for(y=0;y<200;y=y+10){
                var p = canvas2.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                document.write(p[0] + " " + p[1] + ' '+' '+p[2]+' ' +p[3] +';\n');
            }
        }
```

The first method works fine, but in the second method, though the image in displayed on the canvas, all the function returns is stream of 0 0 0 0 s

What might be the mistake ?

Comment: Why do you use `document.write`?

Comment: I just wanted to see the output, used this instead of console.log because the second function was giving output there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are not waiting for the image to finish loading (loading images is asynchronous) so you are iterating the image data before the load callback is invoked so the image is never drawn to the canvas before this.

If you move the iteration inside the load handler it should work:

```
$(image).load(function() {

    canvas2.drawImage(image, 0, 0,200,200);  

    for(var x=0;x<200;x=x+10){
        for(var y=0;y<200;y=y+10){
           var p = canvas2.getImageData(x, y 1, 1).data;
            document.write(p[0] + " " + p[1] + ' '+' '+p[2]+' ' +p[3] +';\n');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine for me:

```
var canvasElement = document.getElementById("text"),
    canvas = canvasElement.getContext("2d"),
    x, y, p;

canvas.fillStyle = "#ff6633"
canvas.fillRect(0,0,200,200);

for(x=0;x<200;x=x+10){
  for(y=0;y<200;y=y+10){
    p = canvas.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    console.log(p[0] + " " + p[1] + ' '+p[2]+' ' +p[3]);
  }
}
```

Maybe you forgot to draw anything on the canvas, or into the region of the canvas you are checking?

Comment: Instead of filling the canvas, can you check it with loading the image onto canvas like this ctx0.drawImage(image, 0, 0,200,200);

Comment: @Tomarinator you didn't tell anything about loading images, and putting them into the canvas. A canvas always contains some image, although it might be transparent. In case you want to load an image, and put it into the canvas, you have to wait until the image is loaded, and then put it into the canvas, and then do the measuring.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just made an edit to the question to clarify on this part.